# Python import requires module name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydev

I have two .py files in the same directory on PyDev in Eclipse like so:

```
DemoProject
|
+---- __init__.py
|
+---- demo_functions.py
|
+---- demo_runner.py
```

In the demo_runner.py file, I attempted to import demo_functions using

```
import demo_functions
```

but PyDev labels this as a problem import. It likes

```
import DemoProject.demo_functions
```

though. The project runs even though PyDev doesn't like it. Any idea what's wrong with PyDev?

Comment: Try: `from demo_functions import *`

Comment: It sounds like the real problem is that both the directory `DemoProject` is in, and `DemoProject` itself, are on your module path. (You can check this by adding a `print(sys.path)` to the top of your script.) If you do that, then `demo_functions` and `DemoProject.demo_functions` end up as two different modules, with separate copies of any global state, and you're almost guaranteed to run into confusing problems later. If that's your problem, you need to fix it (never ever allow a package to appear on `sys.path`), which is probably a matter of your project configuration in PyDev.

Comment: Removing the project folder from sys.path fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you should have added 'DemoProject' as your source-folder in PyDev (this is the folder to be added to the PYTHONPATH) instead of letting the project base directory in the PYTHONPATH.

You can change that at your project configuration (select project in the pydev package explorer > alt + enter > pydev - pythonpath)

As a note, you probably don't want the `__init__.py` at that level (since that's your top-level and not a package).

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't sound like anything is "wrong" with it per se. You *should* be using [full/correct imports](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) and not hoping that the interpreter knows what you're talking about, especially since [newer versions of Python only support proper imports](http://python3porting.com/problems.html#relative-import-problems).

```
from . import demo_functions
```

Comment: Ohh, okay. I was unfamiliar with that change in Python 3. Thank you.